# Error: field ‘rwsem’ has incomplete type

Tags: c, module, linux-kernel, semaphore

I have a module. It has a header file : circular_buffer.h

```
typedef struct _buffer_entry_{
       char data[1024];
       int size;
       struct rw_semaphore rwsem;
}buffer_entry;
```

when i compling. there are a error : rwsem has incomplete type?
How can i fix it?

Answer (score 4):

Do the forward declaration of the `struct rw_semaphore` before defiing `struct _buffer_entry_`.

Alternatively, If this is in the header file, you can define  `_buffer_entry_` before defining `rw_semaphore` so you can avoid forward declaration.

Comment: I use struct rw_semaphore by include semaphore.h. My header file same: 
#ifndef _CIRCULAR_BUFFER_
#define _CIRCULAR_BUFFER_

#include <linux/semaphore.h>

typedef struct _buffer_entry_{
    char data[1024];
    int size;
    struct rw_semaphore rwsem;
}buffer_entry;
How can i fix my header?

Comment: There's no definition of struct rw_semaphore in semaphore.h So your include has no effect on the error. Where's rw_semaphore defined?

Comment: there's example use rw_semaphore in semaphore.h. My module same. there 's no need to defined rw_semaphore ???

http://tuxthink.blogspot.com/2011/05/reader-writer-semaphores-in-linux.html

Comment: Here's the code for semphore.h. I don't the see the defintion of rw_semaphore there. http://tomoyo.sourceforge.jp/cgi-bin/lxr/source/include/linux/semaphore.h

Comment: I just declare struct semaphore in my header instead use struct rw_semaphore. also there is no error more.
big thk to U Thiruvalluvar :)